# starting out in winsock cant get the first bit to compile

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, winsock

apologies for having to create a new thread for this but I'm starting out in winsock and have been following through [madwizard](http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/4) and [beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) guides, and also some information on msdn. I'm stuck and I cant seem to compile the following (yeahp...big start..i know..:P )

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    const int iReqWinsockVer = 2; // 
    WSADATA wsadata;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(iReqWinsockVer,0), &wsadata) == 0 ){
        if (LOBYTE(wsadata.wVersion) >= iReqWinsockVer){


        }
        else{
            cout<<" Required version Not available..." << endl;
        }
        if (WSACleanup()!=0){
            cout<<"Clean up failed!..." << endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Startup faled!..." << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I'm receiving the following errors

```
C:\DOCUME~1\rs\LOCALS~1\Temp/ccygafwl.o:sock.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
C:\DOCUME~1\rs\LOCALS~1\Temp/ccygafwl.o:sock.cpp:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using GCC and compiling through the command-linem is there anything that I must link?.

-Thank you.

Comment: I think `-lws2` works. Stretching my memory though.

Comment: Do you mean you use Mingw or GCC via Cygwin? Why not just use a free Express Edition of Visual Studio for Windows specific code?

Comment: Mingw, I'm trying to avoid visual studio at the moment, Don't really know how to useit, and I don't think something as simple as this really needs such an IDE :). Still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link your project against the winsock library using `-lws2_32` (*if I remember correctly*).

Answer (score 1):

> gcc -o socket.exe socket.c -lws2_32

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you didnt link with with win socket lib (Ws2_32.lib in vissual studio)

Comment: hello, I'm not using visual studio, just GCC and notepad++. How do I do this manually?

Comment: I think you need this -lws2_32